# Is there an alternative to (py)tesseract for extracting text from game screenshots?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I need to to extract text from a screenshot taken from a game window in python. So far, I have been using tesseract (pytesseract) but while the recognigion itself is great, the performance is not optimal.

As I have read that tesseract is best used for high resolution images, I'm wondering if there is a better (faster) way?

Answer (score 0):

I use [gImageReader](https://github.com/manisandro/gImageReader/) for ocr.
It's a frontend on the tesseract library and provides many features for improving performance as well.